# Why isn't make detecting changes in header dependencies

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  I'm trying to get make to figure out what dependencies my project has for, not only source files, but non-system included header files.  I've many resources from this very site related to this subject.

Such as: [Makefile header dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15725861/988207) and [Makefile, header dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2501715/988207)

However, when I do

```
touch MyHeader.h
```

as a test to see if this works, my make process fails to rebuild the source files that include this header.  So, here's what I have in my makefile (of relevance that is)

```
CPP=g++
CPPFLAGS=-Iadditional/includes -MMD
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++0x -c 
# not every source file in this directory needs to be included in this build
# this is because of shared code with Windows
SOURCESFILTER = File1.cpp File2.cpp

OBJ_DIR=obj
SOURCES = $(filter-out $(SOURCEFILTER),$(wildcard *.cpp))
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o))

DEPENDENCIES = $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)

.PHONY: archive

archive : $(OBJECTS)
    ar mylib.a obj/*.o

-include $(DEPENDENCIES)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SOURCES) $(DEPENDENCIES)
    $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

I've verified that the above process does indeed generate the expected *.d files.  I assume that I'm including them correctly.  However, as mentioned, as a test I do:
    touch MyHeader.h

which is in the same directory as the sources, and rerun the make, none of the source files which include this header are remade.  What am I missing?

Andy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you cannot include prerequisites in a suffix rule.  Even if you could, you certainly would *not* want to include `$(SOURCES)` or `$(DEPENDENCIES)`, because that would cause *every* object to rebuild whenever *any* source or dependency file changed.

Second, you cannot create the target file in a different directory from where make expects it to be.  Make will put the place where it wants to find the target in the variable `$@`, and you must write the output into that location exactly.  If you ever see a rule that modifies the target, such as above where you use `obj/$@`, that won't work.

Most likely GCC is writing the files as `obj/foo.d`, but your `include` is trying to include `foo.d` but that doesn't exist... but since you used `-include` make doesn't complain.

I recommend you first write the object files into the local directory and get that working with dependencies.  Once that works, then read up on how to write targets to a different directory and/or ask again.

ETA:

Try something like this:

```
CXX := g++
CPPFLAGS := -Iadditional/includes -MMD
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++0x
# not every source file in this directory needs to be included in this build
# this is because of shared code with Windows
SOURCESFILTER := File1.cpp File2.cpp

OBJ_DIR := obj
SOURCES := $(filter-out $(SOURCEFILTER),$(wildcard *.cpp))
OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o))

DEPENDENCIES := $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)

.PHONY: archive

archive: mylib.a

mylib.a: $(OBJECTS)
        $(AR) $@ $^

-include $(DEPENDENCIES)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Thank you for the push in the right direction.  I understand now that my make file targets were all wrong.  I have changed this and will update the text I posted here after submitting this comment.  I've copied the the make file to try hacking at building them local to the directory.  That works, but I get a strange error at the beginning, "fatal error: opening dependency file obj/*.d.d no such file".  Indeed there isn't.  This is from the make file where it's being built locally????

Comment: That error doesn't look quite like a make error.  Did you cut/paste it?  Or paraphrase?  I recommend you change your `=` to `:=` in your variable assignments.  Also as I mentioned before, having `$(SOURCES)` and `$(DEPENDENCIES)` as prerequisites of your pattern rule is really not right.  Everything will rebuild all the time.  You don't want the dependencies as prerequisites of anything, and you should use just a single `%.c` as the prerequisite.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for you help.  This was what I needed.  I was pretty close to the answer, but just wasn't quite there.  I wasn't sure how to make filters work on pattern rules, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp.  This seemed that it would compile every source file and clearly I didn't want that.  I haven't found in the GNU manual yet how the SOURCES variable affects this but apparently this is what I want.  Thanks again.