# Makefile not recompiling on header file change

Tags: c++, makefile

I have 2 `.cpp` files : `main.cpp` `A.cpp` and few header files in `include` dir.

I am trying to write a makefile that recompiles whenever a header file changes.

Now I tried following the method outlines in the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725789/makefile-header-dependencies). However I could not get started. Here is my attempt so far.

```
CC := g++
OBJS := main.o A.o
OUTPUT := program.exe
INCLUDE_DIR := -I ./include \

#linking step
all: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIR) $(OBJS) -o $(OUTPUT)

#compile and generate dependency info
%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIR) -c $*.cpp -o $*.o 
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIR) -MMD -c -o $@ $<

-include *.d
```

Comment: What do you mean you "could not get started"? What's the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not including your dependency files correctly. The wildcard there doesn't do what you want. It'd be simpler to just:

```
DEPS = $(OBJS:.o=.d)
-include $(DEPS)
```

To actually use a wildcard with the dependencies, you'd have to do:

```
-include $(wildcard *.d)
```

Note that gcc actually lets you generate the dependency and the object files at the same time. This could simplify your rule. Also I find it better to explicitly state where everything is going, in case of any issues:

```
%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIR) -c $< -o $@ -MMD -MF $(@:.o=.d)
```

Comment: Could you explain how the line with `-MMD` and `-MF` flags works?

Comment: @SU3 See [Preprocessor Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html), specifically the description for `-M`.

Comment: The `MF` flag is pointless when `MMD` is used, contrary to the `MD` flag.

Comment: @Chnossos False. From the documentation "When used with the driver options -MD or -MMD, -MF overrides the default dependency output file." If you want to put the dependency outfile files somewhere other than the default, that's what `-MF` is for.

Comment: Yeah, I should've added "when used like you did in your answer" since you're basically doing manually what is done automatically.

Comment: @Chnossos I like being explicit.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, I for one like to be minimalist, so I thought indicating that fact could be useful to someone else like me :)

Comment: Please remember to include this after the All, or it will check the receipt and then exit

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the header files in the dependencies' list. For example:

```
%.o : %.cpp %.hh
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIR) -c $*.cpp -o $*.o 
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIR) -MMD -c -o $@ $<
```

If you have an `a.hh` for every `a.cpp`.

The make file syntax is

```
target: dependency_1 dependency_2 etc
    rule
```

All the dependencies are checked for when they were updated last time, and if either of them has a time stamp more recent then the target, the rule is executed. In your Makefile, you don't have any headers in the list of dependencies.

Comment: There may not be a %.hh for every %.cpp, and the whole point of autogenerating the dependencies is to get them correct.

Comment: @Barry I understand that, that's why I wrote "**If** you have an `a.hh` for every `a.cpp`". Also, I just expanded the answer.

Comment: That's a large assumption that is probably never going to be true, made even more unnecessary by the fact that the goal of OP is to have the compiler generate the correct dependencies for him via the `*.d` files. This answer is just wrong.