# Makefile individual header dependencies

Tags: makefile

I have the following Makefile which works fine but is not very elegant.

```
bin/a.gb: obj/main.o obj/i.o obj/in.o obj/g.o obj/an.o obj/s.o obj/b.o obj/b_m.o obj/b_r.o obj/b_e.o
    /opt/gbdk/bin/lcc -Iinclude -Wa-l -Wl-m -Wl-j -Wl-y -Wl-w -Wf--debug -o bin/a.gb obj/main.o obj/i.o obj/in.o obj/g.o obj/an.o obj/s.o obj/b.o obj/b_m.o obj/b_r.o obj/b_e.o

obj/main.o: src/main.c include/common.h include/i.h include/in.h include/an.h
    /opt/gbdk/bin/lcc -Iinclude -Wa-l -Wl-m -Wl-j -Wl-y -Wl-w -Wf--debug -c -o obj/main.o src/main.c

obj/i.o: src/i.c include/common.h include/i.h include/b_m.h include/b.h
    /opt/gbdk/bin/lcc -Iinclude -Wa-l -Wl-m -Wl-j -Wl-y -Wl-w -Wf--debug -c -o obj/i.o src/i.c

obj/in.o: src/in.c include/common.h include/in.h include/g.h
    /opt/gbdk/bin/lcc -Iinclude -Wa-l -Wl-m -Wl-j -Wl-y -Wl-w -Wf--debug -c -o obj/in.o src/in.c

obj/g.o: src/g.c include/common.h include/g.h
    /opt/gbdk/bin/lcc -Iinclude -Wa-l -Wl-m -Wl-j -Wl-y -Wl-w -Wf--debug -c -o obj/g.o src/g.c

obj/an.o: src/an.c include/common.h
    /opt/gbdk/bin/lcc -Iinclude -Wa-l -Wl-m -Wl-j -Wl-y -Wl-w -Wf--debug -c -o obj/an.o src/an.c

obj/s.o: src/s.c include/s.h
    /opt/gbdk/bin/lcc -Iinclude -Wa-l -Wl-m -Wl-j -Wl-y -Wl-w -Wf--debug -c -o obj/s.o src/s.c

obj/b.o: src/b.c include/b.h
    /opt/gbdk/bin/lcc -Iinclude -Wa-l -Wl-m -Wl-j -Wl-y -Wl-w -Wf--debug -c -o obj/b.o src/b.c

obj/b_m.o: src/b_m.c include/b_m.h
    /opt/gbdk/bin/lcc -Iinclude -Wa-l -Wl-m -Wl-j -Wl-y -Wl-w -Wf--debug -c -o obj/b_m.o src/b_m.c

obj/b_r.o: src/b_r.c include/b_r.h
    /opt/gbdk/bin/lcc -Iinclude -Wa-l -Wl-m -Wl-j -Wl-y -Wl-w -Wf--debug -c -o obj/b_r.o src/b_r.c

obj/b_e.o: src/b_e.c include/b_e.h
    /opt/gbdk/bin/lcc -Iinclude -Wa-l -Wl-m -Wl-j -Wl-y -Wl-w -Wf--debug -c -o obj/b_e.o src/b_e.c

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    find bin obj -type f \( -name '*.gb' -o -name '*.o' -o -name '*.ihx' -o -name '*.cdb' -o -name '*.map' -o -name '*.noi' -o -name '*.adb' -o -name '*.lst' -o -name '*.sym' -o -name '*.asm' \) -exec rm {} +
```

In order to make it more streamlined and generalized so that I don't have to edit it as much for every new source file, I came up with the following:

```
IDIR=include
BDIR=bin
ODIR=obj
SDIR=src
CC=/opt/gbdk/bin/lcc
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR) -Wa-l -Wl-m -Wl-j -Wl-y -Wl-w -Wf--debug

DEPS := $(wildcard $(IDIR)/*)

_OBJ = an.o b_e.o b_m.o b_r.o b.o g.o i.o in.o main.o s.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))


$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SDIR)/%.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

$(BDIR)/a.gb: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/* *~ core $(IDIR)/*~ $(BDIR)/*
```

This also works.  The only drawback so far is that it loses the association of which header files are dependencies for which object files.  So with the original Makefile, if I changed the contents of a single header file, only the object files whose sources include that header got rebuilt.  But now, if *any* of the header files are edited, it rebuilds *all* of the object files.  Is there a clever way around this?  I'd like for my new, streamlined Makefile to only rebuild the necessary object files if a header file is changed.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725789/makefile-header-dependencies/15725861#15725861) solution but I'm having a hard time understanding how to incorporate it into my new Makefile.  I don't understand the purpose of the `-include $(ODIR)/*.d` line, for instance or where that would go.

EDIT: I realize now that the solution that I linked may not work for the lcc compiler, as it does not appear to have the -MMD option (at least as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any number of extra dependencies to a rule next to the declared recipe:

```
$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

$(ODIR)/an.o: $(DEPS)/dep1.h $(DEPS)/dep2.h $(DEPS)/dep3.h
$(ODIR)/b_e.o: $(DEPS)/dep1.h $(DEPS)/dep3.h
```

(Using `patsubst` to reduce the boiler plate left as student exercise)

There is also the `.EXTRA_PREREQS` variable in GNU Make 4.3, which is more handy when the prerequisites are not meant to be part of the recipe, https://lwn.net/Articles/810071/ :

> New feature: .EXTRA_PREREQS variable
>
> Words in this variable are considered prerequisites of targets but they are
> not added to any of the automatic variable values when expanding the
> recipe.  This variable can either be global (applies to all targets) or
> a target-specific variable.  To detect this feature search for 'extra-prereqs'
> in the .FEATURES special variable.